# How to make headerTitle to fit into headerBackground with react navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I am using the react navigation library with react native, I want to create a custom header by using the headerBackground and headerTitle screen options.

I need a robust way for the headerTitle component to use all the available space, but remains inside the limits of the screen.

So far I have ([Snack link](https://snack.expo.dev/@ericjavierhernandezsaura/custom-header-title-component?platform=ios)):

```
function App(): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          options={{
            headerBackground: () => (
              <View
                style={{
                  flex: 1,
                  backgroundColor: 'red',
                  borderColor: 'green',
                  borderWidth: 4,
                }}
              />
            ),
            headerTitle: props => (
              <View
                style={{
                  backgroundColor: 'blue',
                  flex: 1,
                }}>
                <Text>Header Title</Text>
              </View>
            ),
          }}>
          {() => <SafeAreaView />}
        </Stack.Screen>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Note I have inlined styles and other bad practices just to make the code shorter for this question.

The results is the following:

[image: screen shot with the result]

Note how the headerTitle component grows without limits.

Is there a robust way to deal with this issue ? Note I am trying to avoid getting/using the dimensions of the device, as in the header can be other content such as backButton, or other options buttons on the right side.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

here is code example you can see to run this code may be this will help you:)

App.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  Button,
  View,
  Text,
  ImageBackground,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image
} from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

const image = { uri: 'https://reactjs.org/logo-og.png' };

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Details"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function DetailsScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{}}>
      <ImageBackground source={image} style={styles.image}>
      <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={()=>navigation.navigate("Home")}
      >
      <Image source={{uri:"https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/128/189/189254.png"}} style={{width:30,height:30,marginLeft:10,marginTop:20}}/>
      <Text style={{fontSize:30 ,color:'white',textAlign:'center',fontWeight:'bold',marginTop:-40}}> hello world</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </ImageBackground>
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Home"
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  image: {
    width: "100%",
    height: 60,
  },
  text: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 42,
    lineHeight: 84,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    backgroundColor: '#000000c0',
  },
});

export default App;
```